# Access SharePoint Rest api via Java Client but get 403 error

Tags: java, rest, sharepoint, adal

I'm trying to access SP Rest API as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29610635/1654763), but still get 403 - Forbidden error.
I'm not sure if it has something to do with the single sign-on we use:
To access the Rest Api via browser I have to login into `https://login.microsoftonline.com` and then I am able to call `https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext=%27Search%20foo%20bar%27`
So my Java App looks like this:

```
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY),
            new NTCredentials("username@mycompany.de", "password", "https://login.microsoftonline.com", "microsoftonline.com"));
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
            .build();
    try {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext=%27Search%20foo%20bar%27");

        System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        try {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
```

Which leads to `HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN`. Any ideas?

EDIT:
I added a print.out of all headers, so my full output is:

```
Executing request GET https://***.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext=%27Search%20foo%20OR%20bar%27 HTTP/1.1
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
----------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/xml;charset=utf-8
Expires: Mon, 15 Jun 2015 07:12:48 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 30 Jun 2015 07:12:48 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
X-Forms_Based_Auth_Required: https://***.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=/_layouts/15/error.aspx&Source=%2f_vti_bin%2fclient.svc%2fsearch%2fquery%3fquerytext%3d%2527Search%2520foo%2520OR%2520bar%2527
X-Forms_Based_Auth_Return_Url: https://***.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/error.aspx
X-MSDAVEXT_Error: 917656; Zugriff+verweigert.+Zum+%c3%96ffnen+von+Dateien+an+diesem+Speicherort+m%c3%bcssen+Sie+zun%c3%a4chst+zur+Website+wechseln+und+die+Option+zur+automatischen+Anmeldung+aktivieren.
DATASERVICEVERSION: 3.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-IDCRL_AUTH_PARAMS_V1: IDCRL Type="BPOSIDCRL", EndPoint="/_vti_bin/idcrl.svc/", RootDomain="sharepoint.com", Policy="MBI"
SPRequestGuid: c757159d-a063-2000-20ed-499660c844ff
request-id: c757159d-a063-2000-20ed-499660c844ff
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.4121
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
Date: Tue, 30 Jun 2015 07:12:47 GMT
```

I try to translate the `X-MSDAVEXT_Error` to english: `Permission denied. To access data from this location you have to switch to the website and enable the option for automatic login.`

Comment: What message do your get from the `403` response? Anything about the security validation?

Comment: @Daniel B see my edit

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Office 365. I've seen this issue when attempting to use some accounts. I'd take a look at the ADAL libraries for performing authentication against Azure AD (Which you have as part of O365) https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java

Comment: Yes, I use O365. Thanks for mentioning ADAL, but I don't really get how to use the authentication sample (I think it's [this example](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java/blob/master/src/samples/public-client-app-sample/src/main/java/PublicClient.java)) with my HttpGet request. Maybe someone could explain?